# Is this possible or ChatGPT is telling me rubbish

Tags: token, smart-contract

Ability to mint after mint authority is gone.

Design the Emergency Minting Logic:
Define the conditions under which emergency minting should be triggered. This could include scenarios such as the burn of the original mint authority, a governance vote, or a specified time period.
Develop the emergency minting logic within the token contract. This logic should allow for the minting of tokens under emergency conditions while adhering to any predefined rules or constraints.

Integrate Emergency Minting Functions:
Implement functions within the token contract that facilitate emergency minting operations. These functions should be callable by authorized parties or triggered automatically based on predefined conditions.
Ensure that emergency minting functions are designed to prevent abuse or unauthorized minting. Implement access control mechanisms, such as multi-signature authorization or governance-based approval, to regulate emergency minting actions.

Handle Emergency Minting Events:
Implement event handling mechanisms to notify stakeholders and users when emergency minting occurs. Emit events within the contract to signal the minting of tokens under emergency conditions, providing transparency and visibility into minting activities.

use solana_program::{
account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
entrypoint,
entrypoint::ProgramResult,
msg,
program_error::ProgramError,
pubkey::Pubkey,
sysvar::{clock::Clock, Sysvar},
};

// Define your token state struct
struct Token {
// Define your token state variables here
}

impl Token {
// Define your token methods here
}

// Define your program entrypoint
#[entrypoint]
fn emergency_mint(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
) -> ProgramResult {
// Extract accounts
let authority_account = next_account_info(accounts)?;
let token_account = next_account_info(accounts)?;

```
// Implement your emergency minting logic here
// For example, you can check if the authority account has been burned or revoked
// If the mint authority is gone, mint tokens to the token account

Ok(())
```

}

// Other entrypoints and functions for your token contract...

// Define your entrypoint handler
pub fn entrypoint_handler(
program_id: &Pubkey,
accounts: &[AccountInfo],
instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
// Implement dispatch logic here
// Match instruction data to call the appropriate function, such as emergency mint

```
Ok(())
```

}

// Define your entrypoint
entrypoint!(entrypoint_handler);

Comment: This is rubbish, sorry!

Comment: Yeah, decided to put more effort and finally understanding than relying on ChatGPT.